# Sidekiq: args in perform_async sent as string instead of actual objects or ActiveRecord::Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, rails-activejob

On replacing perform_later call of ActiveJob with perform_async of SidekiqWorker, the arguments that I earlier passed as objects and ActiveRecord::Relation are now being sent as String. Is this expected and sync doesn't support ruby objects or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Is this expected and sync doesn't support ruby objects, because sidekiq works with redis, and the memory of redis and rails application is not shared.

[Check Wiki](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Best-Practices#1-make-your-job-parameters-small-and-simple)

Answer (score 1):

This is expected. Since Sidekiq uses Redis as the data store, the arguments need to be serializable.

According to [Sidekiq wiki](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/The-Basics), the arguments must be simple JSON datatypes (numbers, strings, boolean, array, hash). If you want to use ActiveRecord objects, you can pass in their IDs as arguments